# Is $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] a good way to store a user id into a database?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm working on a website that allows users to search for rooms to rent. the users also can 'upload' a new house, once logged in (similar to airbnb)
What I'm looking for is a way to save in the house table the user's id, along with other house info like adress, city, rooms ect, which will be gained from a form. So far I've build the database like this

```
CREATE TABLE `house` (
  `house_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ....... (other house details),
   `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`house_id`),
    KEY `house_user_user_id_fk` (`user_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `house_user_user_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`),)
```

So far I've tried to do something like this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['listhouse'])) {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        # input from form stored in variables
         $query = "INSERT INTO house(price,title,description, city,street,user_id)
        VALUES('$price','$title','$description','$city','$street','$user_id')";
        $res = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$res) {
            die('something went wrong' . mysql_error());
        } else {
            header("Location: profile.php");
        }
    }
}
```

I need a way to relate a certain house with a certain user.

Comment: I didn't think there is any problem in that.

Comment: Please don't use "mysql_*" statements because they are deprecated: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: No need to worry. You can continue with this way. it will not harm your security as well.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, this is a feature request.

Comment: @Y.Hermes yes I know, I am changing all my mysql statements to mysqli, I will change this one too. Just needed to make sure I'm on the right track with the rest of the code